# Run middle part of code in iPython console

Tags: python, ipython

I want to run middle part of code, for example, from line 30 to 90 in train.py in iPython console. Does anyone knows how to do that?

I know how to this command
`%run -d -b 90 script.py` can run from line 1 to line 90, but not from 30 to 90.

Answer (score 2):

The command you're running doesn't really do exactly what you say it does. It runs the program under the control of `pdb` and sets a break point at line 90. So you could continue execution if you wanted.

You can load up functions, classes or specific lines using `%load`, but that won't run the commands under control of `pdb`.

eg.

```
%load -r 30-90 script.py
```

Will be transformed into the those lines, which you can then either run directly, or edit before running.

To load specific functions or classes from the file you can use `-s`

```
%load -s MyClass script.py
```